# How to instantiate multiple custom views in Android?

Tags: java, android, xml, view, android-custom-view

I'm really confused about custom views.

I need to define a custom view, consists of an `ImageView` and a `TextView`. And then I want to change the contents of this views, according to a php json response, which I have accomplished.

First of all, which way should I go :

**1)** Define the custom view as an XML, then "inflate" , duplicate, whatever, and then change the newly instantiated text's and image sources etc ?

**2)** Define the custom view as a Java class, and instantiate it ?

In the end, I want to instantiate my custom views as children of a vertical layout.

What I'm currently trying is, path #**2**. I defined this class :

```
public class ArizaSatiri extends LinearLayout { 
    TextView arizaTitle;    
    //constructor :
    public ArizaSatiri(Context context, AttributeSet attrs)
    {
        super(context, attrs);        
        // add title , description etc : 
        arizaTitle = new TextView(context);
        arizaTitle.setText("abcef defefef");
        this.addView(arizaTitle);        
    }    
}
```

Then I tried this in my main activity :

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_arizalarim);

        ArizaSatiri as = new ArizaSatiri(getApplicationContext(), attrSet);
    }
```

But I have no idea how to construct an AttributeSet.

So please tell me, which path should I choose, and how to accomplish to instantiate a custom view, as many times as I want, dynamically ?

Answer (score 1):

Attribute set is constructed when you add your component via xml. You have to define custom component's attributes in attrs.xml. (http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidCustomViews/article.html#additional_attributes)

If you do not want to create your view from xml then just remove attribute set from the constructor as LinearLayout has a constructor without the attr set: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/LinearLayout.html#LinearLayout(android.content.Context)

Comment: Am I guaranteed to be safe if I use the constructor with single (context) parameter? If so, great :) I can add layoutParams inside (or after) the constructor, right ?

Comment: what do you mean "safe"? it'll work correctly. For example see http://startandroid.ru/en/lessons/complete-list/220-lesson-16-creating-layout-programmatically-layoutparams.html 
You can add layoutParams after call to the super. You can even create constructor: public ArizaSatiri(Context context, LayoutParams params) {super(context); setLayoutParams(params); }.